# Eclipse GEF FanRouter

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-gef, draw2d

I am using GEF to create a tool that visualises dependencies between files. I successfully managed to do the connections between nodes and I can also switch the functionality to use the `ManhattenConnectionRouter`.

However I find trouble using the `FanRouter`.

I tried following the logic example that GEF provides, but I still have problems. Unfortunately there is no other tutorial that shows how to implement a `FanRouter`.

Here are excerpts of my code:

The base class, implementing the `FreeformLayer`:

```
public class DependencyGraphPart extends AbstractGraphicalEditPart implements LayerConstants {

    private DependencyGraphAdapter adapter;

    public DependencyGraphPart(){
        super();
        adapter = new DependencyGraphAdapter();
    }

    @Override protected IFigure createFigure() {
        FreeformLayer layer = new FreeformLayer();
        layer.setLayoutManager(new FreeformLayout());
        layer.setBorder(new LineBorder(1));

        return layer;
    }

    @Override protected void refreshVisuals(){
        ConnectionLayer cLayer = (ConnectionLayer) getLayer(CONNECTION_LAYER);
        cLayer.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
        AutomaticRouter frouter = new FanRouter();
        cLayer.setConnectionRouter(frouter);
    }
```

And here my ConnectionClass:

```
public class DCDependencyPart extends AbstractConnectionEditPart{       
    private DCDependencyAdapter adapter;
    private Label label;

    public DCDependencyPart() {
        super();
        adapter = new DCDependencyAdapter();
    }

    @Override protected void createEditPolicies() {
        installEditPolicy(EditPolicy.CONNECTION_ENDPOINTS_ROLE, new ConnectionEndpointEditPolicy());
    }

    @Override
    protected IFigure createFigure(){
        PolylineConnection conn = new PolylineConnection();
        conn.setLineWidth(conn.getLineWidth()*2);
        conn.setConnectionRouter(new FanRouter());
        conn.setTargetDecoration(new PolylineDecoration());
        conn.setToolTip(new TooltipFigure());

        label = new Label("1"); 
        label.setOpaque(true); 
        label.setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.buttonLightest); 
        label.setBorder(new LineBorder()); 
        conn.add(label, new MidpointLocator (conn, 0)); 

        return conn;
    }
```

When I tried to implement the `ManhattenConnectionRouter` I had no problems doing so by just adding it to the Connection-class. (No modification of the `DependencyGraphPart`)

These are the two places where I make actively usage of any `Router`.
Unfortunately I don't know draw2d and/or GEF well enough to find my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FanRouter is the router for handling collisions. It requires the "next" router which can be BendpointConnectionRouter for example that would do the all the hard work for laying out a connection.
Once Fanrouter is laying out a connection it would first use the "next" router to do the actual connection layout and after that would check if this connection overlaps with any other connections with the same source and target and if yes it would introduce extra bendpoints to ensure conneftions don't overlap each other.
Below is the example of proper usage of FanRouter:

```
AutomaticRouter router = new FanRouter();
router.setNextRouter(new BendpointConnectionRouter());
connectionLayer.setConnectionRouter(router);
```

Comment: So, I've added the `BendpointConnectionRouter()` to the Editpart class just as in your example. Do I have to add these things also to the Connection-class or should I remove the routing completely from there?  
Also: do I need a BendpointEditPolicy if I don't want to save them to the model?

Comment: No, you don't need the edit policy for bendpoints, since it enables editing of bendpoints which you don't want. Routing is set on the connection layer, so for all connections. Remove router setting added manually for connection figures.